# Encoding powers in HTML

Tags: html, encoding, character-encoding

What is the correct way to display powers in HTML is it correct to use superscript or is there power tags that should be used?

50x10<sup>9</sup>

Comment: It's probably overkill for exponents alone, but I just want to mention we have [MathML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/MathML) for laying out more complex mathematical content. [Something like this](https://jsfiddle.net/ajedv94f/) in your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use superscript tag. There is no other power tag in HTML.

```html
50x10<sup>9</sup>
```